# Is there a way to access the variables currently on ipython from a python script without passing them as arguments?

Tags: python, ipython

I can access a "running variable" in an ipython session just by using its name:

```
In [1]: foo = 5

In [2]: foo
Out[2]: 5
```

I want to access `foo` from within a new script I run. Something like this:

```
# script.py

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # for example
    bar = foo + 1
    print(bar)
```

And then:

```
In [3]: run script.py
Out[3]: 6
```

I can obviously pass them as arguments and access them from `argparse`, but I want to know if there is a way of accessing all of these "running variables" in a session.

Comment: You should pass values as arguments, but that does not mean as command line arguments parsed by argparse. Just make a function which takes arguments and call that function.

Comment: Yes, I don't think what you want to achieve is possible because in general variables defined in a script are not accessible to other scripts. So what you can do is pass them as arguments or define them in a `shared` file and then import them into the new script. Of course, in this way, you have to update the shared file each time you want to change the variables but may be faster than passing them when you are calling the script from the console each time.

Comment: Check the help/docs for `%run`.  I think there's a parameter to run in the 'global' environment.

Comment: @zvone and Domiziano thanks for your comments! The problem with passing the variables as arguments to the script/any function in the script is that I don't have a determined number/names of variables in the session. I have to basically try if a particular variable is in session and use it if it is.

Comment: That makes no sense. If your function is using some variable, it has to be determined which variable it is using.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I found is running the `script.py` (using the same script from the question) using a flag `-i` [doc](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) in ipython:

```
In [4]: run -i script.py
Out[4]: 6
```

This is still something workable for my project. Hope this helps anyone looking for a similar application.